# Our spring batch job is having only one step. We have reader, processor,writer Operations in the step. How to stop proceeding to processor step

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

Our spring batch job is having only one step.we have reader, processor, writer Operations in the step. How to stop proceeding to processor step when prior step is failing?

Comment: You only have 1 step? So how could that be prevented? Unless you mean when reading fails but then everything stops already. In short your questions isn't very clear.

Comment: See if this helps https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-skip-logic#1-using-skip-and-skiplimit

Answer (score 0):

You reader is implementing something like this:

```
public class MyReader implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {
```

In that case you can use the ExitStatus to signal the error.
For example:

```
  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {


    return ExitStatus.FAILED;
  }
```

In this case batch processing will stop and no more processing occur.

`afterStep` is available from `StepExecutionListener`.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ExitStatus.html